# Check whether a given number is pronic (product of two consecutive integers) using RECURSION. e.g. 12=3*4

Tags: java

I am trying to check whether a given number is pronic (the product of two consecutive integers), specifically in a recursive fashion.

I tried the following, but don't understand how the recursion should look like:

```java
int i = 0;

boolean check(int n) {
    if (i < n) {
        if (i * check(i + 1) == n)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you tag so many languages?

Comment: Don't spam tags with several languages

Comment: You can turn any loop into recursion. So solve it with a loop first.

Comment: Solve it with a loop first, and then try to make the recursion by thinking what happens in the loop for which it breaks. Also, you don't need to spam tag several languages.

Comment: Is recursion a good way of solving this?  Or is it just a requirement for your homework?  The square root of the number gets you close to what the answer might be.

Comment: @john i have solved it with a loop i'm a high school student so just cant think of a recursive way to do it

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah actually it a requirement in this question

Comment: @AdityaSingh Going around a loop is just like a recursive call. Give me a second and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Just like a loop, recursion must have a condition where it ends. Your recursion doesn't have such a condition.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the condition here should be that it runs until i<n but thats not the problem part mate

Comment: Actually, you can just solve the quadratic equation `c = n^2 + n`. The solution is `n = sqrt(c + 1/4) - 1/2`.

Comment: That code isn't valid in any of the languages the question is tagged with.

Comment: In C: `bool check(int value, int guess) { int pronic = guess * (guess + 1); if (pronic == value) return true; else if (pronic > value) return false; else return check(value, guess + 1); }` — called as `bool result = check(12, 1);`.  The code doesn't take care to avoid integer overflow — it probably doesn't need to for your homework, but would if you were writing general-purpose code.  (Warning: untested code — this is only a comment, not an answer!)

Comment: @ndc85430 I'm obviously giving a mathematical formula.

Comment: The condition to end the recursion includes a recursive call. So to know if you should end the condition you must do a recursive call, which must do a recursive call, which must do... And so on in infinity (or the stack runs out). Is there a value of `v` that should end the loop? Then use that. Or perhaps you should rethink the logic so you start with a high value of `v` and then count *down* until `v` becomes zero or negative? Try that in a loop first. Perhaps you need another argument to the function (to be honest both `n` and `i` should probably be arguments)?

Comment: Oh wait a minute... What is the argument `v` even used for? The function never uses it. Perhaps it *should* use the argument variable `v` somewhere?

Comment: `int foo(int target, int cur, int value) {if (target == value) return 1; if (target < value) return -1; foo(target, cur+1, value + 2 * cur); }` and `int bar(int target) {return foo(target, 2, 2); }`

Comment: @AdityaSingh I recommend readding the tag `c++` simply because the only answer to this question is written in C++.

Comment: Hint: Use that `X[n + 1] = X[n] + 2 * n` and `X[2] = 2` It's fast and easy.

Comment: Why did you include a second language tag *again*? Don't do that, choose one language.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code. `check` is a conventional solution using a loop. `check2` is the same code turned into a recursive function. Notice how recursively calling `check2` is like going around the loop again in `check`. This kind of recursion is called *tail recursion*.

I'm assuming efficiency is not a requirement here. There are some useful suggestions for improvements in the comments below. But the main point is to illustrate that loops and recursion are just alternative ways of doing the same thing.

```
#include <iostream>

bool check(int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        if (i*(i+1) == n)
            return true;
        ++i;
    }
    return false;
}

bool check2(int n, int i)
{
    if (i == n)
        return false;
    else if (i*(i+1) == n)
        return true;
    else
        return check2(n,i+1);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << check2(n, 0) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can use `if (i * (i + 1) > n) return false;` which terminates quicker (by a large margin for large values of `n`).

Comment: @python_user I honestly don't know, I knew the question would be closed (usual prejudice against newbie questions), so I coded up the solution as fast as I could, posted it, and then noticed that the question was closed.

Comment: @python_user: if you've started an answer before the question is closed, you now seem to be able to post the answer.  I think that's a new(ish) behaviour.  I spotted it recently (in the last month or so); I don't think that was always the case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Interesting, that's a good thing I think.

Comment: @john In any event, congrats 

Comment: On the whole, I agree that being able to post an answer after the question is closed if you started the answer before the question was closed is a good thing.  ISTR there were complaints many years ago on MSO about it.  I expect there is a time limit — but I've no idea what it is — such that you need to post the answer within N minutes of the question being closed.  I'd expect N to be somewhere in the region of 10 minutes, but anything from 5-60 minutes would be fairly reasonable. I don't know if there's been an announcement on MSO or MSE about this — or whether I'm hallucinating like ChatGPT.

Comment: In the `check` function, `i` isn't incremented inside the loop.

Comment: @Thiyagu Thanks, fixed now. I did test check2 but obviously not check.

Comment: Much better performance can be achieved by using `X[n + 1] = X[n] + 2 * n` and `X[2] = 2`